# Is there a way to push large files to a remote server using System.Net.Http.HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to push a 50 MB file to a remote server using System.Net.Http.HttpClient:

```
private async void Transfer_Product_Upgrade_Package(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await UploadFileAsync();
}

async Task UploadFileAsync()
{
    string filename = @"C:\AccountView\AccountViewPublish\ProductPackage.zip";

    Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:3748/api/UploadProductPackage/5");

    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StreamContent(stream));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

I'm getting this response without even hitting the target server:

Response status code does not indicate success: 413 (Request Entity Too Large).

A smaller file is being transferred using the same exact code just fine.

Is there a way to deal with larger files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default maximum IIS 7 upload filesize is about 28mb. For bigger file size, you need to configure IIS 7 to allow bigger size using WebConfig:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Also, ASP.NET runtime has additional limit. You can change that here:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" />
</system.web>
```

Check this [link](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/) for more info.